# Facebook xfbml multiple appIds on one page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a problem with facebook apps. 
I have two diffrent apps with two appIds. I`d like to have them both on one page.
If I use the iframe it is no problem. If I use the following , hmm. I dont know how to get 2 appIds in one page.
By the way, does anybody know, how to deactivate the comment function in the like-button?

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {FB.init({
  appId  : 'APP_ID_1',
  status : false, // check login status
  cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
  oauth : false, //enables OAuth 2.0
});


  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(targetUrl) {
   _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'like', targetUrl]);
});
```

FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(targetUrl) {
       _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'unlike', targetUrl]);
    });
};

```
  (function() {
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js';
e.async = true;
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
```

}());

```
<?php //like button ?>
<fb:like layout="button_count" font="arial" href="http://www.example.com/eeee"></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, an APP ID must be linked to a single domain. Please see the "Site URL" field on your App Settings (https://developers.facebook.com/apps). You will not be able to authenticate (or perform call which require authentication, dialogs, etc.) from two different APP IDs on the same URL. You might be able to combine both APPs code on a single one. Why do you need two different APP IDs?

If you detail the functionality you want to achieve I might be able to suggest you an alternative solution.

Many thanks

Daniel Torvisco - Developer Support Engineer at Facebook

Comment: OK, I try to clearify my case. On our site we have a like and arecommend button. the first one points to facebook.com/our_company. The second one points to www.our_company.de/url. One links to the main facebook AppId the second one is an extra app in the same fb-account. We try to get the real statistics for both. Am I thinking the wrong way, with that?

Comment: There are so many difference use case that we would want to use 2 access token in one web page. Such as login ourself as admin of webpage and as a user of app at the same time. There are real app and test app with difference appId and we would want to login those in the same time. Possibility is unlimited so please stop trying to lock something unneccessary. Your engineer team is annoying facebook

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `iframes`, just add the contents you want in two different iframe sections (*use JS to control both of them*). There're going to be a few problems with layouting the screen, but I'm sure your designers can work with it. Regarding that thing someone told about security, that's bullshit. You can define as many Apps as you want, and within each App you have as many domains as you want. For testing in different domains, just configure your `/etc/hosts` file with the same domains you defined in the App (*on Windows I known that there's a `hosts` file, don't know where it is though*). If you want to use some specific FB API calls, then you can find a few problems and it can be really trick to workaround those OAuth necessities for authentication and authorization, but for just the buttons you asked, it should be pretty easy to implement.

Hope it helps. Best,